# Best ways to automate Cordova Android App Build

Tags: cordova, cordova-android, cordova-hooks

We are using Cordova to build android apps. We have three different types of apps with each pointing to different URLs(two for testing and one production). We will be building all the three apps and would like to automate the build process. Below are our requirements and I have few findings. Please correct me if I am wrong:

1. Update the URL accordingly - this I believe should update content tag in config.xml
2. Update App Name, package, version code, version name etc - this can be done by updating config.xml or manifest via hooks. which is better?

Please note an input to differentiate each app will be passed via command line. Rest of the details should be taken from configuration files and update.

Is there any better way of doing it?

I am thinking of doing this in before_prepare hook.